# System.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust; Not Found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I been beating my head against the wall trying to get this to work.  I have a project I did a while ago that used JWT to authenticate users.  When I copied the template code from one project to the other, It claimed to be missing a package or libary. I check nuget and apparently I have installed the latest version of the frameworks I need.

Any suggestions for what i am doing wrong?

[image: It cannot find the protocol]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the assembly is showing any warnings under Project -> References. I've sometimes found that one has a warning. Most commonly this is because there is a mismatch in the .Net version.

I've had a package add a .net 4.5.2 assembly into a project targeting .net 4.5 which exhibited similar behavior.